# why is my code really slow and how can i improve it?

Tags: python, performance, pygame

**this is my code idk why it runs so slow**
why is my code running so slow plz help me!
thank you in advance

```
import pygame
from rgb import *
from pygame.constants import *
pygame.init()

height=700
width=1500
center=(780, 450)
ball_pos=[500,550]
sky_pos=[0,-1000]


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.display.update()

running=True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_SPACE]:
            running=False
            pygame.display.update()
    sky=pygame.image.load("sky.jpg")



    if keys[K_RIGHT]:
        sky_pos[0]-=1
    screen.blit(sky, sky_pos)

    class Circle:
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, green, ball_pos, 50)
    pygame.display.update()
    screen.fill(black)

pygame.quit()
```

I tried doing everything but nothing is working
i want the sky to move to the left with smoothness though i dont know how!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in your code, but the most obvious thing is that you are loading the image into the application loop. `pygame.image.load` is very time consuming, because it has to read the images from the data store.

Load the image once **before** the application loop, rather than continuously **in** the loop:

```py
sky=pygame.image.load("sky.jpg")      # <--- ADD

running=True
while running:
    # [...]

    # sky=pygame.image.load("sky.jpg")  <--- DELETE
```

Comment: ok thanks it is working now